# Python tkinter Checkboxes double check/uncheck

Tags: python, checkbox, tkinter

I have a problem with tkinter checkboxes in python.

I use two checkButtons in a grid layout.

```
class GUI (Tk):
...    
    def __init__(self, parent):
        Tk.__init__(self, parent)
        self.parent = parent
        self.varA = 0
        self.varB = 0
        Checkbutton(self, text="Do A", variable=self.varA, command=self.onCheckButtonAPressed).grid(column=1, row=7, sticky='WESN')
        Checkbutton(self, text="Do B", variable=self.varB, command=self.onCheckButtonBPressed).grid(column=2, row=4, sticky='WESN')
...
```

When I click on one of them, the variable is changed correctly, but with one click on one of them, both are checked/unchecked and I don't know why.. :(

Comment: Should this be a toogle mode where only one can be activated?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `variable` option is reserverd for special var-objects of tkinter.
Also you should split inititalization of your Object and adding it to your Layoutmanager (`.grid()`) so you have a reference to your object later.

```
class GUI (Tk):
    def __init__(self, **options):
        Tk.__init__(self, **options)
        self.varA = IntVar()
        self.varA.set(0)
        self.varB = IntVar()
        self.varB.set(0)
        checkbox_a = Checkbutton(self, text="Do A", variable=self.varA, command=self.onCheckButtonAPressed)
        checkbox_a.grid(column=1, row=7, sticky='WESN')
        checkbox_b = Checkbutton(self, text="Do B", variable=self.varB, command=self.onCheckButtonBPressed)
        checkbox_b.grid(column=2, row=4, sticky='WESN')

    def onCheckButtonBPressed(self):
        print self.varB.get()

    def onCheckButtonAPressed(self):
        print self.varA.get()
```

Comment: self.varA.set(0) is not needed, because the default value is 0. =)
Thx for your answer! :) But it is a little strange, because with one checkbox IntVar() is not needed...

Comment: You can also set the option `onvalue=0` so its your Checkbox is "checked" if the intvar is 0